# Render gpu use 1 core cpu!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, opencl

There are things that I do not understand. When you use gpu only uses 1 core. Solution or explanation?
Blender 2.78 release 1475052116
[image]

Amd fx 8120
ram 16gb 1600
ssd 120 kingstone + hdd sata3 500 gb
gtx 970 sc evga 
linux mint 18

Comment: @David Not sure this is really a duplicate; it looks to me like this is asking why only one *CPU* core is used during GPU rendering, and the other questions is asking why only one *GPU* core appears to be used.

Answer (score 4):

When rendering an image using the GPU, the data somehow needs to be loaded from your disk, preprocessed, pushed into RAM, from there into VRAM where the GPU finally starts doing its job. Everything up until the point where the data enters VRAM is done by the CPU.

If your GPU is working at 100% there is simply no need to push more data into this pipeline, so it's actually a good idea to not occupy more of the CPU's cores than necessary. In fact, this one CPU core won't even reach 100% unless your system runs out of RAM. In this case the CPU starts swapping the content of the memory onto the hdd, which ultimately will rise the CPU load.

So there's no solution needed, the system manages its own resources quite fine.

Comment: Sorry that not speak well english.
But the question is that this does not generate bottleneck?.
The cpu usage is almost always 100%, but I sense that need more. To be an amd fx 8120 uses shared resources, if you see the cpu3 - 35%. What worries me is whether use of a core only Rendering GPU for a long time.
In addition when begins blender to work with the GPU core that you touch, is responsible to end the process. And does not share the burden in other cores or to be rotary switch.